# How can I make a 3D mouse act the same as in other programs?

Tags: interface, 3d-mouse

I can't seem to get my 3D mouse (3DConnexion SpaceNavigator) to work 'right' in Blender.

The intended functionality is that rotations should be orbiting the object and the mouse should be able to pan/zoom. This is the functionality in all the other major 3D programs I've used (eg C4D, Modo, Rhino, NX).

However, in Blender, it seems that you can either set 3D mice to orbit around the object and lose the ability to pan, or the motions are completely decoupled from the object you've chosen, resulting in the object tending to move off screen.

Any clues on a way to work this out?

Comment: You may be looking for the "Trackball" orbit style. This can be found under the Input tab in the User Preferences.

Comment: You can orbit around by holding down MMB and dragging mouse. If you hold down SHIFT and use MMB, you will pan. If you need to return your mouse to the selected object, you can hit NUMPAD PERIOD button. If you want to have a WASD walk-like navigation, hold-down SHIFT and press F and you will be in "fly mode".

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, I'm talking about 3D mice. Not basic interaction.

Comment: @someonewithpc : trackball does not do the trick, as the pivot is still not at the selected object, but rather at a global pivot. Turntable also suffers from this, but Z axis is locked.

Comment: Vincent, some of this may not be the fault of the mouse. Your question does not specify the mode (edit or object) that you're in, and the statement about motions that are *completely decoupled from the object you've chosen* suggests to me the possibility that the issue here might be a consequence that you're working in edit mode with an object whose vertices, are not conforming to the origin of the object. The key to the latter issue is to go to object mode, and apply (CTRL - A key) the scale, rotation, and translation transforms.

Comment: That or pressing Numpad . (dot) to recenter at the selected object/vertex.

Comment: @brasshat Nope. Not in edit mode. Also pretty sure that wouldn't change anything for this question.

Comment: @someonewithpc a point of this is to be able to orbit the object even if it's not centered in the view.

Comment: I am suffering the same thing.  I was starting to wonder of my brand new spaceNavigator is defective. So glad you stated this question so perfectly. I was having trouble characterizing it.  @vincent-lee did you work this out somehow?

Comment: It's hard to help without access to the hardware. I suspect it should be easy if Blender input events can properly read all the required input of the 3D mouse. If not, then it's pretty hard. You should probably check with the manufacturer of the 3D mouse for support as well.

Comment: I've discovered since I wrote my comment that "3d Mouse" == "NDOF device".  This synonym discovery opens up a whole world of more options!  I am going answer the question unless someone with an NDOF device wants to answer with advice about their favorite settings.  Now today my NDOF device has stopped working so I can't try my new settings -- frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Just change navigation style of NDOF device to one which you like - orbit around selection or free. Trackball lets you bank the camera There isn't any other option I'm afraid there's no way to arbit around selected with ability to pan in 3d connexion mouse